# Div contents don't appear on button press in anything other than jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsfiddle

I have a script that opens a div where you can change the time of a timer, and it opens on a button press. This works fine in fiddle, the div opens up and the div contents appear, but other IDEs don't work (Coding Rooms, Programiz, pretty much any other online IDE)--the div never appears. The code is below. Any solutions or explanations?

Is it maybe because JSFiddle uses a different version of JS? I honestly have no idea.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/acharbonneaucs/w4todhy0/324/)  so you can see the full code.

```js
var setTimeMenu = document.getElementById("setTimeMenu");
var openTimeSetMenu = document.getElementById("setTimeMenuOpenButton");
var closeTimeSetMenuSpan = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

openTimeSetMenu.onclick = function() {
  setTimeMenu.style.display = "block";
}

closeTimeSetMenuSpan.onclick = function() {
  setTimeMenu.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == setTimeMenu) {
    setTimeMenu.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.timeTypeText {
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  display: inline;
}

.timeAmountText {
  display: inline;
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14pt;
}

.centerVertical {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}


.Modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: +1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.modalContents {
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;

  font-size: 14pt;

  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 70%;
}

.close {
  color: #ffffff;
  float: right;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #cccccc;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input {
  background-color: white;
  border: thin solid blue;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding: 0.5em 3.5em 0.5em 1em;
  transform: scale(80%);
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}

input::placeholder {
  overflow: visible;
}

select,
input {
  background-color: #ededed;
  border: thin solid blue;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding: 0.5em 3.5em 0.5em 1em;
  transform: scale(80%);
  margin: 0;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}

select.minimal {
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, gray 50%),
    linear-gradient(135deg, gray 50%, transparent 50%),
    linear-gradient(to right, #ccc, #ccc);
  background-position:
    calc(100% - 20px) calc(1em + 2px),
    calc(100% - 15px) calc(1em + 2px),
    calc(100% - 2.5em) 0.5em;
  background-size:
    5px 5px,
    5px 5px,
    1px 1.5em;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

select.minimal:focus {
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(45deg, green 50%, transparent 50%),
    linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 50%, green 50%),
    linear-gradient(to right, #ccc, #ccc);
  background-position:
    calc(100% - 15px) 1em,
    calc(100% - 20px) 1em,
    calc(100% - 2.5em) 0.5em;
  background-size:
    5px 5px,
    5px 5px,
    1px 1.5em;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-color: green;
  outline: 0;
}

select.minimal:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}


select:-moz-focusring {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
}

.ButtonStyle {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  border: thin solid blue;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: max;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ButtonStyle:hover {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 5px #97B1BF;
  color: #000;
}

.ButtonStyle:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 300%;
  padding-left: 350%;
  margin-left: -20px !important;
  margin-top: -120%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}

.ButtonStyle:active:after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0s
}

.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.65;
  filter: alpha(opacity=65);
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.not-allowedCursor {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

input {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="setTimeMenuOpenButton" class="ButtonStyle">Set School Closing Time</button>
  <div id="setTimeMenu" class="Modal">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div class="modalContents">
      <p align="center" style="font-weight: bold;">Change the time and date to when your Summer vacation starts!</p><br>
      <input id="timeInputBox" pattern="[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}" size="10" maxlength="8" placeholder="Time:">
      <p align="center" style="font-size: 9pt; font-weight: bold;">You must use the format "hr:min:sec" to change the time! Time must also be in military time!</p>
      <p align="center" style="font-size: 9pt; font-weight: bold; color: grey;">e.g.: 14:06:00</p>
      <input type="submit" class="ButtonStyle" style="transform: scale(120%); font-size: 16pt; margin-left: 23px; padding-left: 45px; padding-right: 45px" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="timerDiv" align="center">
    <div class="timeTypeText">Days: </div>
    <div class="timeAmountText"><span class="days"></span></div><br>
    <div class="timeTypeText">Hours: </div>
    <div class="timeAmountText"><span class="hours"></span></div><br>
    <div class="timeTypeText">Minutes: </div>
    <div class="timeAmountText"><span class="minutes"></span></div><br>
    <div class="timeTypeText">Seconds: </div>
    <div class="timeAmountText"><span class="seconds"></span></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: How are you running this? What do you mean by "it doesn't work in other ide"? Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: what do you mean by "but other ide dont work"? where this doesn't work?

Comment: @HarshRohila, CodingRooms, JSEditor.io, pretty much every other online ide.

Comment: The code you posted here isn't remotely close to what you posted on jsFiddle. Please update your question.

Comment: @j08691 Yeah I was just posting the important stuff...

Comment: Obviously you didn't post a [mcve] in your question if the working code on jsFiddle isn't here for us to debug

Answer (score 0):

If you download the JSEditor.io code you will notice the script tag is added in `head` so the script is not able to find the elements in `body` so the code is not working